# Trigger 'Add another term' using javascript

Tags: forms, ajax, javascript

Is there any way to simulate the click event of 'Add  another term' using javascript?
I tried like this

```
 jQuery('#edit-field-attribute-und-add-more').trigger('click');
```

but no effect

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
jQuery('#edit-field-attribute-und-add-more').click();
```

Comment: tried that, but no effect. I need the event that is bound with Add another term be invoked